# SQL Server Where condition optimisation

Tags: sql

Hi I am new to SQL Server 2008 , when i execute the below query in SQL Server its not displaying data from the source table. I believe the below query can be optimized to get the data correctly. If anyone helps me to do that, i will be very thankful to them.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Report
WHERE  ( ( Create_Date BETWEEN '10/10/2013 16:00:00' AND '10/16/2013 15:59:59' )
          OR ( Date_Resolved BETWEEN '10/10/2013 16:00:00' AND '10/16/2013 15:59:59' )
          OR ( ( ( Create_Date < '10/10/2013 16:00:00' )
                 AND ( Date_Resolved > '10/10/2013 16:00:00' ) )
                OR ( ( Create_Date < '10/10/2013 16:00:00' )
                     AND ( IsDate(Date_Resolved) IS NULL ) ) )
          OR ( ( ( Create_Date < '10/16/2013 15:59:59' )
                 AND ( Date_Resolved > '10/16/2013 15:59:59' ) )
                OR ( ( Create_Date < '10/16/2013 15:59:59' )
                     AND ( IsDate(Date_Resolved) IS NULL ) ) ) )
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of `Create_Date` and `Date_Resolved`?

Comment: 'optimizing' and 'correcting an incorrect query' are two different requests.. so people answering might not get what you want. You have to be more clear in your questions.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008 I believe the default date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD' not 'MM/DD/YYYY'. Is the format correct?

Comment: For Martin Smith, both datetime datatypes.

Comment: For sksallaj , the query is not giving any errors while executing so i think its not syntax error, SQL Server is executing for long time but it is not ending. I have waited for 1.5 hours and stopped the query.

Comment: @user2890655 - What are you trying to do with the `ISDATE` check then? Also use `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` as the format.

Comment: How many rows are in the table? If you have been waiting 1.5 hours then maybe you are blocked by an open transaction.

Comment: Its around 0.5 million

Comment: Martin, will try removing the ISDATE and changing the Date format. Will let you know the result if it comes correct.

Comment: Martin, Great the query completed in 2.57 mins. Thank you very much for your advise. I am very thankful to you.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone who helped me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This query is a mess. I removed unnecessary brackets, reorganized and merged conditions, formatted the sql and removed duplicated `OR` conditions (one says: `Create_Date<'10/16/2013 15:59:59'`, second says `Create_Date < '10/10/2013 16:00:00'` and both say `IsDate (Date_Resolved) IS NULL`, so you can safely delete the former. And it's done two times :)).

Here's what you get, and it does exactly the same thing:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM Report
WHERE  

Create_Date BETWEEN '10/10/2013 16:00:00' AND '10/16/2013 15:59:59' 
OR 
Date_Resolved BETWEEN '10/10/2013 16:00:00' AND '10/16/2013 15:59:59' 
OR ( 
    Create_Date < '10/16/2013 15:59:59' 
    AND 
    Date_Resolved > '10/16/2013 15:59:59' 
)
OR ( 
    Create_Date < '10/10/2013 16:00:00' 
    AND (
        Date_Resolved > '10/10/2013 16:00:00' 
        OR
        IsDate (Date_Resolved) IS NULL 
    )
)
```

I still don't know why it's not working, but it should be easier to figure this out now :).
Btw, what does `isDate()` do, and what's your rdbms? Could you post sample data and a query on fiddle?